# Trying to edit init.el to customize emacs

Tags: emacs, customization

So I'm relatively new in trying to customize emacs. But I really need to customize is asap. Tabs are a pain in emacs as they are two spaces, and the text is all messed up when it is opened with any other editor after that.

Currently, I only have few lines in my ~/emacs.d/init.el file:

```
(setq load-path (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.emacs.d/"))

(set-scroll-bar-mode 'right)

(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode t)
```

I get an error while starting up emacs:

```
Loading encoded-kb...done


An error has occurred while loading `/Users/mycomp/.emacs.d/init.el':

Symbol's function definition is void: set-scroll-bar-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I tried srtating it with the --debug-init option, but my lisp knowledge is not enough to help me figure out what's wrong. Any help on how to get this working or redirecting me to some GOOD tutorials on editing init.el files will be really helpful (yes i did google tutorials on editing the initialization file, but every one of them was terrible).

I'm assuming my code for getting line numbers on the left is also wrong. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is possible that the version of emacs you are using does not support `set-scroll-bar-mode`. Did you add that line (if so where did you get it?), or did you copy it over from another machine?

Comment: `set-scroll-bar-mode` is available with GNU Emacs at least as old as Emacs 20 (over 10 years old). Dunno whether it is also available with versions older than 20.  Maybe you are using another Emacs than GNU Emacs, and the one you are using does not have `set-scroll-bar-mode`. Dunno whether XEmacs has it, for example.

Comment: I don't think scroll-bars are available when you're using Emacs inside a text terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I think this line may be the problem:

```
(setq load-path (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.emacs.d/"))
```

First of all, I don't think this is required to load `~/emacs.d/init.el`. Secondly, if you **do** want to add a directory to your `load-path`, you should probably be doing it like this instead:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
```

This code **adds** the directory to the `load-path`, your code just clobbers it with the single directory.

Comment: no, that didn't fix it. I still get the same error. It's failing at set-scroll-bar-mode. Would you know how to fix it if at all?

Comment: Does adding this line: (require 'scroll-bar) at the top of your file help? Are you using GNU Emacs or XEmacs, and are you running in a terminal or not?

Comment: I'm using Gnu Emacs. I added the line and it stopped giving me that error. Yes, I'm running it on my mac osx terminal. Doesn't set-scroll-bar-mode add a scroll bar to emacs that helps avoid using C-v and M-v?

Comment: I also just added the line (require 'linum) and it's saying file load error. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you add linum.el to your load path?

Comment: No, I haven't done that yet. How can i add it? something with add-to-list i believed?

Comment: download the file and copy it to ~/.emacs.d/

Comment: A recommendation: you should really get an Emacs with GUI support. Running Emacs inside a terminal is an inherently limited experience as opposed to running it in its GUI window.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'M-x apropos' and 'M-x customize-apropos'. For now, those will make your life much easier when you want to customize things.

For instance, to customize things to do with scrolling, 'M-x customize-apropos RET scroll RET' will give you a list of all things that you can customize that have 'scroll' in them. You can look around and find the things that you want by searching the buffer. If you find a particular thing that you want, there's usually a group that it belongs to. You can click on that, and just customize those particular values. Make sure you save the settings.

It might take you a while to figure out what things are called. If you've got an idea, try the apropos search. If that doesn't turn up anything, google can probably sort it out for you.

For now, don't worry about hacking the elisp. This method will write values to your startup file (probably the .emacs?) and you can look and check the syntax later if you're really interested. I customize most of my stuff this way; I only bother actually modifying the file by hand when I'm trying to write my own hooks or functions.